# iPhone - Create a semi transparent rectangle with opaque text

Tags: iphone, uiview, transparency, uilabel, alpha

I have a MapView and I want to display a black semi transparent rectangle on top with a text inside. Not over the entire map only on section of it (maybe on the top corner) just as an info box (like the one in the iPod player that appears on double tap and displays the Mute and skip buttons).

I tried google but I'm not getting any clear answers. How is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like [this](http://nachbaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/GoogleLogoMoved.png)?

Comment: No, I mean like this http://www.garrettgirod.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/iPhone2.jpg I want to do something like the clock and date, showing some text and over the map.

Comment: Just add a view/label with a non-opaque (< 1) alpha backgroundColor on top. Look into backgroundColor property of view/label and UIColor class methods.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Can be easily done with interface builder:

[image]

### View Hierarchy

**NOTE** *The background has to be a separate view which is the first entry in the list of controls, so it is in the background. Setting the container view to an alpha value below 1 will also be inherited by the subviews, which is not displayed in the interface builder*

[image]

### Settings for view "view with clear color bg and alpha 1.0"

[image]

### Settings for view "black translucent bg view"

[image]

Comment: It seems much easier than I thought! I'll try this when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: If you need this programmatically come back and ask.

Comment: I need to update the label as a timer. But I think that I can do this with IB and then connect it with a UILabel in my code and update that. Am I right?

Comment: Hi I have two questions about this: 
1) The inside label is showing the text with the alpha transparency. How can I change this behaviour? 2) Is possible to hide the transparentt view? I want to show this view only in some occations.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Chompas 1. What behaviour? You'd like to set the alpha of the text as well? 2. yes set: `yourView.hidden = YES;`.

Comment: I did the steps you mentioned above but the text from the UILabel that is inside the View with the alpha at 0.50 has also transparency. I did not find any properties in IB for the UILabel to change this behaviour. I can add a screeshot if you like =)

Comment: Yes of course, and add a screenshot of the expanded view hierarchy as well.

Comment: Here are the screens: [What I see in the app with the text transparent](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/8845/img0242.png) .  [And this is the hierarchy and the view properties](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5018/screenshot20110428at125.png) Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: I see the problem. Ok, it's easily solved, I'll update my answer next week, I'm off to a wedding. However, the short answer is: Create a container view, which holds two views: label and background view. Background view is the same size as the container. Set alpha of container to 1.0 and background color to clearColor. The background view's alpha is 0.5. Now move the label in the hierarchy to the top(same level but first, background is behind the label) if not done already. Interface builder doesn't show the effect of inheriting alpha of subviews.

Comment: Oh, I see the point. I'll try this when I get home. Thanks for your fast answer and have a nice wedding!

Comment: Mmmm I'm doing something wrong here, I'll try to understand your point

Comment: Still no luck with this. Any help?

Comment: @Chompas, sorry, busy week, I've overhauled my answer. Now with a working example.

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm now. I misunderstood you thinking that I had to create one view with two views inside. Thank you very much Nick

Comment: @NickWeaver how can i do this in programmatically

Comment: I'm doing this and no matter what I do the text is always gray instead of white for the label. I've got the color set to white.

Comment: @JeremyHicks This sounds like as if your label is a subview of the view set to semi transparent alpha. Your label has to be "above" the semi transparent view and not a subview of it.

Comment: @NickWeaver realized I was overwriting the text color through code. :(

Comment: @JeremyHicks glad you figured it out and this XCode 3 answer is still working.