# iphone: How to make a Transparency mask over the UIVIEW

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, transparent

Dears, I'm trying to create a mask over the UIView. I tried adding a View with Alpha lower than 1, the problem was, all the alpha of the controls like images, buttons on this View has been set to same value.

How can I only change the background transparent but don't impact other controls?

I also tried UIImageView, but seems UIImageView couldn't attach other controls

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Create a semi transparent rectangle with text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795688/iphone-create-a-semi-transparent-rectangle-with-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [iPhone - Create a semi transparent rectangle with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795688/iphone-create-a-semi-transparent-rectangle-with-text/5796091#5796091) I think you are having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
view.backGroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background color of your UIView like this:

```
yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

HI..

I've done a the same couple of times...what i did was..

I used a `UIView` and then added a `UIImageView` on it..

now add the subviews to the `UIView`..not on the image view..

so now decreasing the alpha of the imageview won't affect the alpha of the subviews added on `UIView`.. ;)

Hope it helps. .

Answer (score 0):

The UIImageView (with any alpha) should be the first control in your view controller. In outline window it must be at the top of controls list inside view container.