# Display Transparent View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xib

I have one ViewControllers, on Button press i am loading one more view controller using [self presentModalViewController:_regViewController animated:YES];

In this view-controller, I am having only one textfield and two buttons.

I want to display transparent view here. I mean , I want to display only the TextField and Two buttons , rest of the things should display its previous view controller transparently (little blur). How it can be done ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795688/iphone-create-a-semi-transparent-rectangle-with-opaque-text check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview:self.backgroundView];
```

But be sure to instantiate the view, as property then synthesize.

Answer (score 0):

When you are modally displaying viewcontroller on another viewcontroller the viewcontroller behind your current viewcontroller gets hidden try to add UIView or viewcontroller's view:-

```
[self.view addSubivew:viewController.view];
```

Else i would suggest to create UIView and add as subview.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot make my viewcontroller transparent to its previous view controller

Comment: Good then , I am ready to add another UIView as a SubVIew. But How to make it transparent except the textfield and buttons

Comment: keep the background transparent or make the background color black and reduce its alpha value to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the view controller try to use view only and make it transparent.
add it to your super view like don't try to present it..

```
[self.view addSubview:your_transparent_view];
```

Comment: I did. I am adding view using the [self.view addSubview:_regView]; and also [self.view setAlpha:0.5]; But all the view is becoming transparent

Comment: don't set [self.view setAlpha:0.5];... set [_regView setAlpha:0.5];
may this will help you....

Comment: It didn't help either. It is making my buttons also transparent

Comment: so what you want make exactly??

Comment: I want the view to be transparent , not the buttons and textfield

Comment: See. I have a image in the View1. When I press a button in the View1, it will load another View2. Which Has one TextField and two buttons. So Here, the View2 will be superview. But I want to see the background view (View1) too , but the view should be little blur type

Comment: u there ? Can You reply me please