# How to make the UIViewController semi transparent

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a two UIViewControllers, and I am displaying the secondViewController modally over the firstViewController. My secondViewController contains a subview which is UIView with some buttons. Now what I want to do is, make the SecondViewController semi transparent  so that my firstViewController is visible and only show the subview modally which is not transparent.

Reagards
Ranjit

Comment: what have you tried have you even tried to do google??? check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795688/iphone-create-a-semi-transparent-rectangle-with-opaque-text

Comment: Hi @Leena I have made my view transparent my making it as a subview and not as modalView, but now I am not understanding, how can I use this to pass data . so any help might be greatful

Comment: can you tell me what problems you are facing???

Comment: Hi @Leena : I have sorted the issues, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you present your view controller, view of previous controller is removed so if you set any alpha for your current controller's view, you will get UIWindow's background.

if you intend to play with the transparency, then instead of doing `presentModalViewController`, in first viewcontroller, `[self.view addSubView:controller2.view];
and make controller2.view.alpha = 0.5;//whatever transparency level u want`

Comment: Hi samFisher, if I make controller2 as a subView , then can I pass data from controller 2 to controller1 because, viewdidappear will not be called .

Comment: Hey if I apply your solution , the alpha value is applied to the subView present in controller2 which I dont want.

Comment: well.. for that you can create and implement your own protocol-delegate mechanism. What I ment like there are alternative ways of passing data from controller1 to controller2 but not for the transparency thing that you are looking for..

Comment: right.. you can set ur controller2.view.color = clear color and set another view over your controller's primary view and set its alpha value

Comment: can I call viewdidAppear, like [firstcontroller viewdidAppear]?.

Comment: Hey, now the firstViewController is totally visible, I want to be semivisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 5.0 and above, you can use the container view controller approach:

```c
// create the modal view controller
MyModalController *modal = [[MyModalController alloc] 
  initWithNibName:@"MyModal" bundle:nil];
[modal willMoveToParentViewController:self];

// add it to the controllers and views hierarchies
[self addChildViewController:modal];
modal.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:modal.view];
[modal didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Then whatever alpha you set for the main view's background in IB or in code will be respected.

Comment: does not work for me.