# UIView color blending mode in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, graphics, colors

**Problem:**

I have what seems like a straightforward issue, but I just can't figure it out.

I have a storyboard in Xcode with three `UIView` that overlap each other; one red `UIView`, one blue `UIView`, and one green `UIView`.

When all `UIView` have an `alpha` of `1.0`, I get the result shown in *Image A*.

When all `UIView` have an `alpha` of `0.5`, I get the result shown in *Image B*.

> **Question:**
>
> 1. How do I get each `UIView` to appear like *Image C* with a difference or additive color blending mode?
> 2. How can I achieve this while each `UIView` moves? (Similar to the effect seen in the Siri wave animation.)

**Images:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlapping UIViews of Differing Color and Alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117072/overlapping-uiviews-of-differing-color-and-alpha)

Comment: Thanks, but that question doesn't address this specific question, it appears out of date and the official documentation doesn't reference a "source over" mode either. The answer selected in that question gives the result of Image B above but not Image C which this question is the focus.

Comment: I think it addresses it pretty well  - you don't have control over this at the View level, which, if you think about it, is what you'd expect.

Comment: I'm focusing on achieving Image C, not Image A or Image B.

Comment: I understand that but since you can't control the blending mode of overlapping views, don't do this using views.

Comment: Hey @user4806509 , I appreciate this question your asking, since I am looking for a very similar thing.  I also agree that the supposed duplicate link provided is outdated and does not really answer your original intent.  

So have you found the solution yet?  If so, could you please share?  It seems that a blendmode is needed with an overlay option, but one that works in real-time, not pre-composited.